# LINQ Get Count of records

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I need to rewrite this SQL query to LINQ EF:

```
SELECT Filter,Attribute,AttributeGroup,AttributeGroupTop,AttributeType,AttributeName,AttributeColor,AttributeSequence,AttributeImage,Sequence,
CASE AttributeType 
WHEN '1' THEN
(Select COUNT(DISTINCT ItemID) FROM NavFilters with(nolock) WHERE Link='lighting' AND SubLink='chandeliers' AND Attribute1=Web_AttributesSchemaEx.Attribute)
WHEN '2' THEN
(Select COUNT(DISTINCT ItemID) FROM NavFilters with(nolock) WHERE Link='lighting' AND SubLink='chandeliers' AND  Attribute2=Web_AttributesSchemaEx.Attribute)
WHEN '3' THEN
(Select COUNT(DISTINCT ItemID) FROM NavFilters with(nolock) WHERE Link='lighting' AND SubLink='chandeliers' AND  Attribute3=Web_AttributesSchemaEx.Attribute)         
WHEN '4' THEN
(Select COUNT(DISTINCT ItemID) FROM NavFilters with(nolock) WHERE Link='lighting' AND SubLink='chandeliers' AND  Attribute4=Web_AttributesSchemaEx.Attribute)         
WHEN '5' THEN
(Select COUNT(DISTINCT ItemID) FROM NavFilters with(nolock) WHERE Link='lighting' AND SubLink='chandeliers' AND  Attribute5=Web_AttributesSchemaEx.Attribute)         
WHEN '6' THEN
(Select COUNT(DISTINCT ItemID) FROM NavFilters with(nolock) WHERE Link='lighting' AND SubLink='chandeliers' AND  Attribute6=Web_AttributesSchemaEx.Attribute)         
WHEN '7' THEN
(Select COUNT(DISTINCT ItemID) FROM NavFilters with(nolock) WHERE Link='lighting' AND SubLink='chandeliers' AND  Attribute7=Web_AttributesSchemaEx.Attribute)         
WHEN '8' THEN
(Select COUNT(DISTINCT ItemID) FROM NavFilters with(nolock) WHERE Link='lighting' AND SubLink='chandeliers' AND  Attribute8=Web_AttributesSchemaEx.Attribute)         
WHEN 'P' THEN
(Select COUNT(DISTINCT ItemID) FROM NavFilters with(nolock) WHERE Link='lighting' AND SubLink='chandeliers' AND  AttributeP=Web_AttributesSchemaEx.Attribute)         
END
AS Count

FROM Web_AttributesSchemaEx with(nolock) WHERE (AttributeType='P' AND Website='LXD') OR (Link='lighting' AND SubLink='chandeliers'  AND Website='LXD')
ORDER BY AttributeType,AttributeSequence
```

This is my code:

```
db.Web_AttributesSchemaEx.Select(e => new
                {                    
                    Link = e.Link,
                    SubLink = e.SubLink,
                    Website = e.Website,
                    Filter = e.Filter,
                    AttributeType = e.AttributeType,
                    AttributeName = e.AttributeName,
                    AttributeSequence = e.AttributeSequence,
                    Count = e.AttributeType == "1" ? db.NavFilters.GroupBy(x => x.ItemID).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).Count(x => x.Attribute1 == e.Attribute && x.Link == link && x.SubLink == subLink) :
                            e.AttributeType == "2" ? db.NavFilters.GroupBy(x => x.ItemID).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).Count(x => x.Attribute1 == e.Attribute && x.Link == link && x.SubLink == subLink) :
                            e.AttributeType == "3" ? db.NavFilters.GroupBy(x => x.ItemID).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).Count(x => x.Attribute1 == e.Attribute && x.Link == link && x.SubLink == subLink) :
                            e.AttributeType == "4" ? db.NavFilters.GroupBy(x => x.ItemID).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).Count(x => x.Attribute1 == e.Attribute && x.Link == link && x.SubLink == subLink) :
                            e.AttributeType == "5" ? db.NavFilters.GroupBy(x => x.ItemID).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).Count(x => x.Attribute1 == e.Attribute && x.Link == link && x.SubLink == subLink) :
                            e.AttributeType == "6" ? db.NavFilters.GroupBy(x => x.ItemID).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).Count(x => x.Attribute1 == e.Attribute && x.Link == link && x.SubLink == subLink) :
                            e.AttributeType == "7" ? db.NavFilters.GroupBy(x => x.ItemID).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).Count(x => x.Attribute1 == e.Attribute && x.Link == link && x.SubLink == subLink) :
                            e.AttributeType == "8" ? db.NavFilters.GroupBy(x => x.ItemID).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).Count(x => x.Attribute1 == e.Attribute && x.Link == link && x.SubLink == subLink) :
                            e.AttributeType == "P" ? db.NavFilters.GroupBy(x => x.ItemID).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).Count(x => x.Attribute1 == e.Attribute && x.Link == link && x.SubLink == subLink) : 0
                }).Where(x => (x.AttributeType == "P" && x.Website == "LXD") || (x.Link == "lighting" && x.SubLink == "chandeliers" && x.Website == "LXD")).OrderBy(x => x.AttributeType).ThenBy(x => x.AttributeSequence);
```

I have a problem with `count` of records. This correct result of `SQL SP`:
http://prntscr.com/9oqsoz
And this is result which I've got:
http://prntscr.com/9oque7
Order of records is correct and other fields are correct too. But I wonder what I've missed? Can anybody help me? It's rather strange but I noticed this bug for such `Link` and `SubLink` only.

Comment: Your where clause in sql query and linq aren't the same OR (Link='lighting' AND SubLink='chandeliers'  AND Website='LXD') in sql and || (x.Link == "lighting" && x.SubLink == "chandeliers")) in linq. extra AND Website='LXD' in sql

Comment: Thaks, but in my code I, of course, have this filter. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the equivalent LINQ expression for your SQL `CASE` expressions should be like this (note the `...COUNT(DISTINCT(ItemID)))..` part of the SQL)

```
//...
Count = 
    e.AttributeType == "1" ? db.NavFilters.Where(x => x.Attribute1 == e.Attribute && 
        x.Link == link && x.SubLink == subLink).Select(x => x.ItemID).Distinct().Count() :
    e.AttributeType == "2" ? ...
```

Comment: Don't help, unfortunately.

Comment: Isn't it generating SQL similar to your original? Also `Web_AttributesSchemaEx` and `NavFilters` are db tables, not views, right?

Comment: Right. And EF generate another sql with cross applyes

Comment: I don''t know, should really be equivalent. Tried to create similar model and query, and see a monster SQL generated with EF but no `CROSS APPLY` inside. `EF 6.1.3` btw, what is yours?

Comment: Vanya, conclusion that I did: rewriting intricate queries - it is very painful ))

Comment: @AlexGurskiy Aboslutely! And the worst thing is, you are totally bound to what EF (version!) will decide to do with what you write, which (in most cases) does not  happen when you write a plain SQL :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this one... instead of your initial query -

```
SELECT
    Filter,
    Attribute,
    AttributeGroup,
    AttributeGroupTop,
    AttributeType,
    AttributeName,
    AttributeColor,
    AttributeSequence,
    AttributeImage,
    [Sequence],
    [Count] = (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT
            CASE WHEN
                    (e.AttributeType = '1' AND n.Attribute1 = e.Attribute) OR
                    (e.AttributeType = '2' AND n.Attribute2 = e.Attribute) OR
                    (e.AttributeType = '3' AND n.Attribute3 = e.Attribute) OR
                    (e.AttributeType = '4' AND n.Attribute4 = e.Attribute) OR
                    (e.AttributeType = '5' AND n.Attribute5 = e.Attribute) OR
                    (e.AttributeType = '6' AND n.Attribute6 = e.Attribute) OR
                    (e.AttributeType = '7' AND n.Attribute7 = e.Attribute) OR
                    (e.AttributeType = '8' AND n.Attribute8 = e.Attribute) OR
                    (e.AttributeType = 'P' AND n.AttributeP = e.Attribute)
                THEN n.ItemID END
        )
        FROM NavFilters n
        WHERE n.Link = 'lighting'
            AND n.SubLink = 'chandeliers'
    )
FROM Web_AttributesSchemaEx e
WHERE (AttributeType = 'P' AND Website = 'LXD') 
    OR (Link = 'lighting' AND SubLink = 'chandeliers' AND Website = 'LXD')
ORDER BY AttributeType, AttributeSequence
```

Comment: Devart, if you find a mistake, can you just tell me? Without hints and tips))

Comment: @Alex Gurskiy your initial query can be simplified and you can get another execution plan... which can be faster... therefore you don't need this `LINQ` :)

Comment: Devart, if I understood you correctly, I need to rewrite. We don't need to use this SP, but need to get correct result. Don't ask me why, it does not matter to me))